# Duplicate method to log out

Tags: android

I'm a beginner and I have (I think) a simple question for you. I have a method used in every `Activity` except `LoginActivity`. It's opened when I click on the shutdown icon. This is code ->

```
public void logOut(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("THIS_CLASS".this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but I do not want to duplicate it in every `Activity`, may exist any solution ? I am writing here because I can't find a solution on the Web.  The problem is that I can not express my intentions in the question on the Internet. Every "duplicate method" gives answers not on the subject. I am not looking for complete code. I prefer only prompt.

Comment: You can use a static method in a Factory

Comment: Hocine B Thank you, for help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the best solution, but if you want a bunch of activities to share the same methods, then create a BaseActivity that they all extend from.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    //... Shared stuff
    protected void logOut() {
        //Do some data cleaning and whatever else you need
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    //... Main code
    private void onLogOutClicked() {
        logout();
    }
}
```

Just make sure you clean out your authentication/session data when this occurs. Try to utilise inheritance for shared functionality.

Comment: great idea, I can do a common class, in which there will be methods used in every activity, and I have several of them :)

Comment: That's pretty much how common functionality is handled my dude. If that works for you, I'd appreciate the upvote :)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I have too little reputation

Comment: It's okay man, hope you get your app working awesomely! Let us know if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create a help class and add a static method like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyHelper {
    public static void startActivityB(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then call the method and pass correct context like below:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         MyHelper.startActivityB(YourActivity.this);
    }
});
```

Note: if `MyHelper`, `LoginActivity`,`YourActivity` are not in a same package, you should import corresponding package, that is an easy job.

Comment: navylover Thank you for help :)